# I don't remember what this phrase was..!! help me out

Tags: expressions

I can't remember what this expression was... 
Here's the situation:

A) Hey, I've got a job, finally!
B) Congratulations! But just make sure to __________, so people can't cheat you.
A) Of course!

So, I guess it was something 'trace the money?' or 'track the bill/money'???
I don't really remember, please help me!

Comment: It could be anything. "Get a written contract," maybe?

Comment: As Mick says, it could be almost anything; it's not a fixed expression.  "Keep track of the money", maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But just make sure to **get it in writing**, so people can't cheat you.